# Getting the text from a plugin title

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the text from this class .cp_widget_content and then the  tag inside of that class. After getting that text, I want to display it in a different div class .testname

But I'm getting errors like getText not being defined. I'm really stuck on this and can't find anything similar online.

This is the html markup:

```
<div class="cp_widget_content">
<b class="cp_widget_title">Portfolio test 2</b></div>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
// PORTFOLIO HOVER
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    (function ($) 
    { 
        $('.cp_widget_content b').hover(function()
        {
            var title = getText('.cp_widget_title');
            $('.testname').text(title);
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

And I want the text to go in here:

```
<div class="testname"></div>
```

Comment: `var title = $('.cp_widget_title').text();`?

Comment: pls add any code (doesn't matter if html, js or some other language) you have as text and not as image

Comment: Now it outputs every .cp_widget_content b title in .testname div instead of the one im hovering over

Comment: That is probably (can't see rest of the code) because you are not using IDs but classes in  your selector. It simply matches more than one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
<div class="cp_widget_content" id="somedivid">
<b class="cp_widget_title" id="somebid" >Portfolio test 2</b></div>

// PORTFOLIO HOVER
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    (function ($) 
    { 
        $('#somebid').hover(function()
        {
            $('#somedivid').text($('#somebid').text());
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```